# Python Regex Date

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying create a regex that looks for all dates in the format MM-DD-YYYY, and this is what I came up with so far:

```
dateRegex = re.compile(r'''
            (0[1-9]|1[0-2])                  # Month 
            -                     
            (10|20|[0-2][1-9]|3[01])         # Day: not [0-2][0-9]|3[01] to avoid 00 matching 
            -
            ((198[0-9]|20(0[0-9]|1[0-6])'''  # Year: matches 1980 - 2016
            , re.VERBOSE)
```

Is there an easier way that allows me to create a range of numbers? And say I wanted to create one that only allows legal dates (for example, June shouldn't have 31 days), would the easiest way just be to match the months with different days, like:

```
((01|03|05|07|08|10|12)-(31 day regex pattern)-(year regex) # for 31-day months
|
(04|06|09|11)-(30 day regex pattern)-(year regex)           # for 30-day months
|
02-(regex depending on leap year))                          # 28 or 29 days
```

Not even sure how I would do the February besides putting all leaps years and 29 days together, and the remaining years with 28 days.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this purely with regex? Wouldn't it be easier to extract all matches to the *basic* pattern (i.e. `\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}`) first, then use e.g. `datetime` to process the results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with jonrsharpe that the way to do this is to combine regex with datetime. I used a simple regex that is going to match anything that *could* be a date in the format, then try to parse them with datetime.

```
import re
import datetime

def yield_valid_dates(dateStr):
    for match in re.finditer(r"\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-\d{4}", dateStr):
        try:
            date = datetime.datetime.strptime(match.group(0), "%m-%d-%Y")
            yield date
            # or you can yield match.group(0) if you just want to
            # yield the date as the string it was found like 05-04-1999
        except ValueError:
            # date couldn't be parsed by datetime... invalid date
            pass


testStr = """05-04-1999 here is some filler text in between the two dates 4-5-2016 then finally an invalid
 date 32-2-2016 here is also another invalid date, there is no 32d day of the month 6-32-2016. You can also not
 include the leading zeros like 4-2-2016 and it will still be detected"""

for date in yield_valid_dates(testStr):
    print(date)
```

This prints the three valid dates:

```
1999-05-04 00:00:00
2016-04-05 00:00:00
2016-04-02 00:00:00
```

Comment: Thanks! Haven't seen re.finditer, datetime, or %m-%d-%Y before, so having some trouble understanding this. What does it mean to parse with datetime?

Comment: @cafeKaze datetime is a python module. `strptime(match.group(0), "%m-%d-%Y")` converts a text in the format MM-DD-YYYY to a datetime object.  The `%m-%d-%Y` is the datetime formatting, you can see all the codes here: http://strftime.org/. `re.finditer` is like re.findall except it returns an iterator of all the matches so you can loop through them

Answer (score 1):

You can use the regex that you have created to extract all such records, seems fine and then perhaps store all the max days of a given month in a list, say:

---

days = [31, 28, 31, 30, etc.]

---

Then for February specifically you might create a function to detect if the given year is leap and use 29 instead of 28 if it is. Also try out the suggestion given by jonsharpe, but if you do that you've still got to check for valid dates, e.g. not the 32nd day of any month.

Answer (score 0):

I find the below RE working fine for Date in the following format;

```
14-11-2017

14.11.2017

14|11|2017
```

It can accept year from 2000-2099

Please do not forget to add `$` at the end, if not it accept `14-11-201` or `20177`

```
date="13-11-2017"

x=re.search("^([1-9] |1[0-9]| 2[0-9]|3[0-1])(.|-)([1-9] |1[0-2])(.|-|)20[0-9][0-9]$",date)

x.group()
```

Output:

> 13-11-2017